# structuring of web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Consider 3 modules/classes in an ASP.NET Webforms application.

I need a web service for each of them, where each web service contains only one function.

Should I group them into one web service class, or should I keep the one web service for each class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are related and need to be exposed for consumtion by a single client you could create one webservice and call this an API. This means you and your client maintain/consume a single webservice.

If they are clearly unrelated, separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Group them in one class (the base webservice class). If it's needed you can branch from here and instantiate more complicated classes, or even call external libraries (for example if you have a data layer to call)